# setInterval() loop still running after clearInterval() is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I know that setInterval() returns a unique ID on every loop, and that clearInterval must be called with that ID to kill the loop. I believe my code does this, yet the loop continues to run indefinitely.

```
var refresh = setInterval(function () {
            $.get(url, function (data) {
                success: {
                    if (data < 5) {
                        data = 5;
                    }
                    var width = data + "%";
                    $("#recalculation-progress-bar").css('width', width);

                    if (data > 99) {
                        clearInterval(refresh);
                        $("#recalculation-message").text("Recalculation complete.");
                    }
                }
            });

        }, 3000);
```

I have checked this in debug and clearInterval() is definitely being called and no errors are thrown. Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: *"Am I doing something obviously wrong?"* Not in that code, no. My guess is that you end up calling it (at least) twice, and so the second time overwrites the value in `refresh`, and so you only cancel the second (or nth) one, not all of them.

Comment: That said, it's always dangerous to combine two asynchronous activities like that.

Comment: Try `console.log(refresh);` before get and before clearInterval to double check they're the same value.

Comment: @Khalid `success: {}` is a `label`. check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: @AhmadIbrahim , thank you I just forgot about javascript labels !! thanks for reminding me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.-

data in $.get is a String by default
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

```
data = parseInt(data)
```

2.-

You add a second level of sync... Are you sure that this request is faster than 3000ms?

3.- If the data is > 99, the code works.

In my concern, the problem is the request is longer than 3 seconds, and you still receive connections that your previously launched.

```
    if (data > 99) {
        clearInterval(refresh);
        $("#recalculation-message").text("Recalculation complete.");
    } else {
    //relaunch here the connection and remove the interval
    }
```

Comment: That is a good point - the request is longer than 3000ms. I will try a quicker request and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Having any luck here?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mark this as answered! I ended up doing something slightly different but based on your answer. Thanks for responding.