# Why my setInterval function doesn't stop

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to write a setInterval function in javascript. Thi is the code:

```
var myTimer=setInterval(function(){ 
        var time=0;

        $.ajax({
            url:'...'
            type: "POST",
            dataType:"",
            success: function (response) {

                if(response=="true" || time>=10000){

                    clearInterval(myTimer);
                }
                time=time+1000;


            },
            error: function () {
                alert("FAIL");
            }
        });


        },1000);
```

I don't know why It doesn't stop in clearInterval. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Have you [tried debugging it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)? It's likely that response never equals `"true"`

Comment: yes it come in the "if"

Comment: "true" try true without the quotations, that checks for the string "true" not an actual Boolean true

Comment: Because your ajax request takes longer than 1000 ms, so the interval elapses many times before you clear it

Comment: probably same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30368368/setinterval-loop-still-running-after-clearinterval-is-called

Comment: That's a good point, what do your mean by *It doesn't stop in clearInterval*?

Comment: @AhmadIbrahim my variable time is like a counter and It identifies how many times the $ajax function must be call. Also if my fuction takes more than one second it doesn't matter!. Why the clearInterval function doesn't stop the setInterval()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Let me illustrate the expected and the actual scenarios to make things clearer.*

**Scenario #1**

The image below shows the case where all your ajax requests complete before one second. You will notice that ajax callback `success` (or `error`) functions will execute only before `clearInterval` (which is what you always expect).

[image]

**Scenario #2**

When some of your ajax requests take more than one second (which is probably what happens), then your ajax callbacks can fire **before** / **after** / **before-and-after** the `clearInterval`, which makes you feel that your `setInterval` *doesn't stop*.

[image]

Note that your `time` variable is useless because it's a function-scoped variable that you initialize to `0` every function call. And even if it's a global variable, it'll only clear the interval in the 11th success function callback, and nothing guarantees how long these 11 successful requests will take.

**Solution**

As [T.J. Crowder suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30393827/2300466), it's better to schedule the next ajax call in the success callback of the previous one, which guarantees that your ajax requests fire sequentially (only one at a time).

*Note*: Because you edited your question after his answer, then you'll also need to edit the if condition like this:

```
success: function(response) {
    if (response != "true" && time < 10000) {
    setTimeout(start, Math.max(0, 1000 - (Date.now() - started)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've claimed that the code does *"come in the 'if'"*, so I assume the `clearInterval` call is actually being made.

Given that, the most likely explanation is that the interval **is** being cleared (after all, [`select` isn't broken](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips)), but before the first `"true"` response, you've **already** made more than one ajax call, and the other ones you're seeing are ones scheduled before the interval was cleared.

E.g., your code runs and:

1. Fires off ajax call #1, which takes more than a second to complete
2. Fires off ajax call #2
3. Ajax call #1 completes but isn't `"true"`
4. Fires off ajax call #3
5. Ajax call #2 completes and is `"true"`, clearing the interval
6. Ajax call #3 completes

Mixing two separate asynchronous intervals (one via `setInterval` and one via `ajax`) is asking for trouble.

If the goal is to make the request once a second and stop when you get back `"true"`, I would have the success handler schedule the next call, e.g.:

```
(function() {
    var time = 0;
    var started = 0;

    start();

    function start() {
        started = Date.now();
        $.ajax({
            url: '...'
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "",
            success: function(response) {
                if (response != "true") {
                    // Schedule the next call to occur one second after we
                    // started the previous call; or almost immediately if
                    // the call took more than a second to complete
                    setTimeout(start, Math.max(0, 1000 - (Date.now() - started)));
                }
                time = time + 1000;
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("FAIL");
            }
        });
    }

})();
```